# How to add data's into pie chart from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pie-chart

I am having a hard time counting the data's from firebase into the pie chart that i made. I have this weird error that I don't know what it is.

I tried counting it and parse it into float as to what it is required.

**This is the method that i used for adding value into the piechard**

```
 public void AddValuesToPIEENTRY(){
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Statistics");
    mUsersDatabase.child("positive").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        int countpositive = 0;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot dataw : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    countpositive = countpositive + 1;
                }
            }
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat((countpositive+"f")), 0));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    mUsersDatabase.child("negative").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        int countnegative = 0;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot dataw : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    countnegative = countnegative + 1;
                }

            }
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(countnegative+"f"), 1));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

**this is the error that im getting**

```
Process: com.example.masternarding.redcrossapp, PID: 6398
                                                                                 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                                     at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.PieChartRenderer.drawDataSet(PieChartRenderer.java:205)
                                                                                     at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.PieChartRenderer.drawData(PieChartRenderer.java:126)
                                                                                     at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart.onDraw(PieChart.java:123)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15122)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14079)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14016)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14079)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14016)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14079)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14016)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14079)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
```

Please, correct my wrong doings in this code.
I need this for today's presentation, help me guys.

Comment: Are you sure that you're setting data for your chart when all your data is already fetched (both firebase callbacks already have fired)?

Comment: Idk what that, all i want is to populate the 2 tables from my firebase into the piechart. That's the reason why I'm here and asking for solution, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MPAndroid doesn't support realtime data which the Firebase provides. This error is caused because your entries is empty. One work around is to fetch the data from firebase on the activity from where you are coming to this activity and send the data through `intent.putextras()` like :
`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putFloat("key1",value1);
bundle.putFloat("key2",value2);
.
.
intent.putExtras(bundle);`
This would not let MPAndroid handle realtime data and will solve your problem.